# Jenkins deploy WAR in glassfish

Tags: jenkins, deployment, glassfish, war

I want deploy in Glassfish a WAR using these batch commands from Jenkins. :

This is how I deploy a WAR with Batch command :
    H:\workspace\xxxx>"C:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat" "undeploy"
    Enter the value for the name operand> xxxx

```
H:\workspace\xxxx>"C:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat" "deploy"
Enter the value for the path operand> H:\xxxx-sources\xxxx.war
Application deployed with name xxxx.
Command deploy executed successfully.
```

In Jenkins , I add a batch command in my build with that :

```
cd "C:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin\"
asadmin.bat "undeploy"
XXXX
asadmin.bat "deploy"
H:\XXXX sources\XXXX.war
```

I have this error :

> Démarré par l'utilisateur anonymous Building on master in workspace
>   C:\Documents and
>   Settings\XXXX.XXXX.jenkins\jobs\deployerXXXXCore\workspace
>   [workspace] $ sh -xe
>   C:\DOCUME~1\XXXX~1.XXXX\LOCALS~1\Temp\hudson2065869118895930371.sh
>   The system cannot find the file specified FATAL: L'exécution de la
>   commande a échoué. java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in
>   directory "C:\Documents and
>   Settings\XXXX.XXXX.jenkins\jobs\deployerXXXX\workspace"):
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified  at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)   at
>   hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:244)   at
>   hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:216)   at
>   hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:802)   at
>   hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:380)  at
>   hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:97)
>     at
>   hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
>     at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
>     at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)  at
>   hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)   at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:533)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the
>   file specified    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.(ProcessImpl.java:81)     at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)  at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)   ... 15 more
>   Build step 'Exécuter un script shell' marked build as failure
>   Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are trying to execute your scripts in Jenkins using shell script execution,which works only on unix-like systems. Try doing the same with Windows batch execution in the Jenkins job.

You should select 'Execute Windows batch command' according to [Jenkins guide](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-ShellScriptsandWindowsBatchCommands).